# Increasing speed of string comparison using mapply

Tags: r

I have data frames containing unique ngrams in the form of:

```
> head(nGram4, 3)
  Term1 Term2 Term3 Term4 Freq
1   the   end    of   the 3457
2   the  rest    of   the 2974
3    at   the   end    of 2950

> head(nGram3, 3)
   Term1 Term2 Term3  Freq
1    one    of   the 15268
2      a   lot    of 13365
3 thanks   for   the 10709
```

and so on down to nGram1 (Term1 and Freq only). The Term columns are character, the Freq column is integer.

For each row, I am trying to pull in the frequency of the lower order nGram table that corresponds to all but the last term column. So for row 1 in nGram3, "one of the", I need to pull nGram2$Freq for the row where Term1="one" and Term2="of". So something like:

```
nGram2[nGram2$Term1==nGram3$Term1 & nGram2$Term2==nGram3$Term2, "Freq"]
```

I'm trying to do this using mapply for each row of nGram3 as follows:

```
mapply(function(xfreq, xterm1, xterm2) 
       nGram2[nGram2$Term1==xterm1 & nGram2$Term2==xterm2,"Freq"], 
       nGram3$Freq, nGram3$Term1, nGram3$Term2)
```

The problem is that I have about 750,000 rows in both nGram2 and nGram3, so this process is terribly slow. I timed a small sample of 100 rows of nGram3 and it takes 7.612 sec.

```
mapply(function(xfreq, xterm1, xterm2) 
       nGram2[nGram2$Term1==xterm1 & nGram2$Term2==xterm2,"Freq"], 
       nGram3$Freq[1:100], nGram3$Term1[1:100], nGram3$Term2[1:100])
```

At this rate, this will take about 16 hours to run through all 750,000 rows. I don't know if there's anything I can do to speed this up. Any thoughts?

**======== TLDR =========**

nGram2 and nGram3 are very big data frames. How can I speed up the following expression:

```
mapply(function(xfreq, xterm1, xterm2) 
       nGram2[nGram2$Term1==xterm1 & nGram2$Term2==xterm2,"Freq"], 
       nGram3$Freq, nGram3$Term1, nGram3$Term2)
```

where Term1 and Term2 are type character and Freq is type integer? As it is, it will take about 16 hrs to run.

Comment: `mapply` would only work if the partial ngrams exactly lined up with the higher order ones. You should think about pasting the values to create a key for lookup or using logical tests using `&`. Or perhaps a `merge` operation....

Answer (score 2):

If you read these in as character-valued columns (using stringsAsFactors=FALSE) rather than factors you can then test whether a merge operation would work (and it does):

```
nGram4[4,] <-c(nGram3[3,],"fish")
merge(nGram4, nGram3, by=1:3)  # could use all.x=TRUE or all.y=TRUE

#   Term1 Term2 Term3 Term4 Freq.x Freq.y
#1 thanks   for   the 10709   fish  10709
```

I just notice the puzzling switch of column positions. I don't understand.